# Radiation pattern and propagation direction

Tags: power, antenna, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, wave

I have a basic doubt about how to read a radiation pattern.

Let's consider precisely the power pattern: it represents how the power is distributed along all directions in space.

For instance, this is the radiation pattern of a dipole antenna:

[image]

What I am able to understand about it is only the fact that it is omnidirectional, that means it radiates equal radio power in all directions perpendicular to the vertical axis, for each fixed point of that axis.

But what I was asking is: is there a link between this diagram and the propagation direction of the radiated wave (I mean the direction of the Poynting vector), the directions of E and H fields, or anyway the wavefront? Is it possible to understand something about them by looking at that diagram?

Comment: The waves propagate outwards in all (omni) directions and hardly anything propagates vertically.